# unable to login with scrapy

Tags: python, scrapy

I'm trying to scrape a page which I have to login first, but for some reason, scrapy crawl another page that have nothing to do, after I use FormRequest. See my code below:

```
# coding: utf-8
import scrapy
from scrapy.http import Request, FormRequest

usuario = 'myemail'
senha = 'mypassword'
urllogin = 'https://ludopedia.com.br/login'
urlnotificacoes = 'https://ludopedia.com.br/notificacoes'

class notificacao(scrapy.Item):
    """Contem os dados dos Anuncios da ludopedia"""
    jogo = scrapy.Field()
    colecao = scrapy.Field()
    tipo = scrapy.Field()
    link = scrapy.Field()


class LoginSpider(scrapy.Spider):
    name = 'ludopedia'

    custom_settings = {
        'CONCURRENT_REQUESTS': 1,
        'LOG_LEVEL': 'DEBUG',
    }
    start_urls = [ urllogin ]

    def parse(self, response):
        return FormRequest.from_response(
            response,
            formname='form',
            formid='form',
            formdata={'email': usuario, 'pass': senha},
            callback=self.after_login,
            dont_filter=True
            )

    def after_login(self, response):
        # check login succeed before going on
        if "Minha Conta" in response.body:
            self.logger.error("Login falhou")
            return


        yield Request(urlnotificacoes)

        self.logger.info("Visitei %s", response.url)
        msg = response.selector.xpath ('//*[@id="page-content"]/div/div/table/tbody/tr[2]/td/a/div[2]/div')
        ...
```

The output of this script is:

```
2017-07-25 12:02:55 [scrapy.utils.log] INFO: Scrapy 1.4.0 started (bot: scrapybot)
2017-07-25 12:02:55 [scrapy.utils.log] INFO: Overridden settings: {'SPIDER_LOADER_WARN_ONLY': True}
2017-07-25 12:02:56 [scrapy.middleware] INFO: Enabled extensions:
['scrapy.extensions.memusage.MemoryUsage',
 'scrapy.extensions.logstats.LogStats',
 'scrapy.extensions.telnet.TelnetConsole',
 'scrapy.extensions.corestats.CoreStats']
2017-07-25 12:02:56 [scrapy.middleware] INFO: Enabled downloader middlewares:
['scrapy.downloadermiddlewares.httpauth.HttpAuthMiddleware',
 'scrapy.downloadermiddlewares.downloadtimeout.DownloadTimeoutMiddleware',
 'scrapy.downloadermiddlewares.defaultheaders.DefaultHeadersMiddleware',
 'scrapy.downloadermiddlewares.useragent.UserAgentMiddleware',
 'scrapy.downloadermiddlewares.retry.RetryMiddleware',
 'scrapy.downloadermiddlewares.redirect.MetaRefreshMiddleware',
 'scrapy.downloadermiddlewares.httpcompression.HttpCompressionMiddleware',
 'scrapy.downloadermiddlewares.redirect.RedirectMiddleware',
 'scrapy.downloadermiddlewares.cookies.CookiesMiddleware',
 'scrapy.downloadermiddlewares.httpproxy.HttpProxyMiddleware',
 'scrapy.downloadermiddlewares.stats.DownloaderStats']
2017-07-25 12:02:56 [scrapy.middleware] INFO: Enabled spider middlewares:
['scrapy.spidermiddlewares.httperror.HttpErrorMiddleware',
 'scrapy.spidermiddlewares.offsite.OffsiteMiddleware',
 'scrapy.spidermiddlewares.referer.RefererMiddleware',
 'scrapy.spidermiddlewares.urllength.UrlLengthMiddleware',
 'scrapy.spidermiddlewares.depth.DepthMiddleware']
2017-07-25 12:02:56 [scrapy.middleware] INFO: Enabled item pipelines:
[]
2017-07-25 12:02:56 [scrapy.core.engine] INFO: Spider opened
2017-07-25 12:02:56 [scrapy.extensions.logstats] INFO: Crawled 0 pages (at 0 pages/min), scraped 0 items (at 0 items/min)
2017-07-25 12:02:56 [scrapy.extensions.telnet] DEBUG: Telnet console listening on 127.0.0.1:6024
2017-07-25 12:02:58 [scrapy.core.engine] DEBUG: Crawled (200) <GET https://ludopedia.com.br/login> (referer: None)
2017-07-25 12:02:59 [scrapy.core.engine] DEBUG: Crawled (200) <POST https://ludopedia.com.br/login> (referer: https://ludopedia.com.br/login)
2017-07-25 12:02:59 [ludopedia] INFO: Visitei https://ludopedia.com.br/login
<200 https://ludopedia.com.br/login>
2017-07-25 12:03:00 [scrapy.core.engine] DEBUG: Crawled (200) <GET https://ludopedia.com.br/notificacoes> (referer: https://ludopedia.com.br/login)
2017-07-25 12:03:01 [scrapy.core.engine] DEBUG: Crawled (200) <GET https://ludopedia.com.br/search?search=&email=myemail&pass=mypassword> (referer: https://ludopedia.com.br/notificacoes)
2017-07-25 12:03:01 [scrapy.dupefilters] DEBUG: Filtered duplicate request: <GET https://ludopedia.com.br/notificacoes> - no more duplicates will be shown (see DUPEFILTER_DEBUG to show all duplicates)
2017-07-25 12:03:01 [ludopedia] INFO: Visitei https://ludopedia.com.br/search?search=&email=myemail&pass=mypassword
<200 https://ludopedia.com.br/search?search=&email=myemail&pass=mypassword>
2017-07-25 12:03:01 [scrapy.core.engine] INFO: Closing spider (finished)
2017-07-25 12:03:01 [scrapy.statscollectors] INFO: Dumping Scrapy stats:
{'downloader/request_bytes': 1357,
 'downloader/request_count': 4,
 'downloader/request_method_count/GET': 3,
 'downloader/request_method_count/POST': 1,
 'downloader/response_bytes': 134813,
 'downloader/response_count': 4,
 'downloader/response_status_count/200': 4,
 'dupefilter/filtered': 1,
 'finish_reason': 'finished',
 'finish_time': datetime.datetime(2017, 7, 25, 15, 3, 1, 355077),
 'log_count/DEBUG': 6,
 'log_count/INFO': 9,
 'memusage/max': 51732480,
 'memusage/startup': 51732480,
 'request_depth_max': 4,
 'response_received_count': 4,
 'scheduler/dequeued': 4,
 'scheduler/dequeued/memory': 4,
 'scheduler/enqueued': 4,
 'scheduler/enqueued/memory': 4,
 'start_time': datetime.datetime(2017, 7, 25, 15, 2, 56, 35121)}
2017-07-25 12:03:01 [scrapy.core.engine] INFO: Spider closed (finished)
```

So, the problem is that, for some reason, I'm getting redirected to **ludopedia.com.br/search?search=&email=myemail&pass=mypassword** but I don't know why.

What I'm trying to do is, visit ludopedia.com.br/login, fill the forms with e-mail and password, then visit ludopedia.com.br/notificacoes and then parse the HTML there.

How can I avoid the link **ludopedia.com.br/search?search=&email=myemail&pass=mypassword** ?

Comment: If it's redirecting from the login submit, I don't think you can avoid it.

Comment: It's a shame, because I can achieve this using curl, like curl https://ludopedia.com.br/login -d email='email' -d pass='password' -c cookie to login and curl https://ludopedia.com.br/notificacoes -b cookie to read the page.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've made it! I think it was a logic problem, here is my working code:

```
# coding: utf-8
import scrapy
from scrapy.http import Request, FormRequest

usuario = 'myemail'
senha = 'mypassword'
urllogin = 'https://ludopedia.com.br/login'
urlnotificacoes = 'https://ludopedia.com.br/notificacoes'

class notificacao(scrapy.Item):
    """Contem os dados dos Anuncios da ludopedia"""
    jogo = scrapy.Field()
    colecao = scrapy.Field()
    tipo = scrapy.Field()
    link = scrapy.Field()


class LoginSpider(scrapy.Spider):
    name = 'ludopedia'

    custom_settings = {
        'CONCURRENT_REQUESTS': 1,
        'LOG_LEVEL': 'DEBUG',
    }
    start_urls = [ urllogin ]

    def parse(self, response):
        return FormRequest.from_response(
            response,
            formname='form',
            formid='form',
            formdata={'email': usuario, 'pass': senha},
            callback=self.after_login,
            dont_filter=True
            )

    def after_login(self, response):
        # check login succeed before going on
        if "Minha Conta" in response.body:
            self.logger.error("Login falhou")
            return

        request = Request(urlnotificacoes, callback=self.parse_notificacoes)
        yield request

    def parse_notificacoes(self, response):
        msg = response.selector.xpath ('//*[@id="page-content"]/div/div/table/tbody/tr[2]/td/a/div[2]/div')
        ...
```

The difference here is that I added, on "after_login" a request to the page I want to scrape, then I've used a callback, to another function to parse the new response, finally I added a "yield request" and then parse the page (now loged in) whit the function "parse_notificacoes".